# I have used event callback function declared withing same calling method using android studio, and looking for equivalent code sample in c#

Tags: c#, android, function, events, declare

For example, I use this in android studio;

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;
            }
        });
```

How can I use same technique in c# to declare the onClick event withing caller procedure?

Comment: button.Clicked += (s,e) => i++;

Comment: Sir Rufo, Thank you for quick answer.